# 1292 error MYSQL: How to convert a column varchar to date with the right format

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to convert all `mm/dd/yyyy` to a SQL readable date in a table/column.

I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `raw` CHANGE `Most Recent PC ENC` `Most Recent PC ENC` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

but it kicks back an error most likely due the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Post the error so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MySQL provide you the ability to migrate data from `varchar` to `date` automatically. Because we can describe a time with string in a variety of formats.

If I were you, I will add a new column with `date` type, and then migrate the data existed in the `varchar` column to the new column manually. As you can use [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) here, so you can achieve this easily.

1. `ALTER TABLE raw ADD COLUMN 'new_column' DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';`
2. `UPDATE raw SET new_column = STR_TO_DATE(old_column, '%m/%d/%Y');`
3. `ALTER TABLE raw DROP COLUMN old_column;`